# How to make a reflexive relationship in Laravel migration and model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I would like to have a `table` that has a `one to many` with itself. Eg: I have like a `people table` that can have many other `people`.This is how my code looks like:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('people', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id')->primary();//Here my PK is a string
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->string('parent_id');//Here is the foreign key of another person
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And in my Person.php model I have this:

```
public function people()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Person')->withDefault();
}

public function person()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Person');
}
```

Take a look to this image:

[image: The relashionship that i'm trying to implement]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Person.php** model:

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Person', 'parent_id');
}

public function child()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Person', 'parent_id');
}
```

Comment: yeah it's a good.... but the name of your one to many relationship is to make **child** like `The Person has many Child`.

Comment: @jochri3 check my edited answer to make parent and child relationship using 'Person' model.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Add parent_id in your migration and define relationship in you model

```
public function people()
   {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Person')->withDefault();
   }

   public function person()
 {
     return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
  }
```

Comment: So,my `migration` file is okay?

Comment: i think parent_id should be nullable

Comment: Yes,you're right the parent_id shoul be nullable.I've done it.Thank also